# Is wearing shorts and leggings under for soccer Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing, awrah

I'm 14 and I dress regularly up to my knees for religious purposes because I know you can not show your features but I am currently in soccer where I wear baddy stuff and long shirts to practice but on game night we need to wear uniforms which consists of shorts and a jersey.

I was going to get large shorts (I am a size small) and wear leggings under. I don't Know if it's haram, I'm not wearing these to try to attract attention from guys I simply just want to play.

So is it haram?

Answer (score 1):

**Shia perspective:** (as you added Shiism tag, it demonstrates you are looking for Shi’I answer(s))

As much as I researched, wearing common sport short in normal way (for men) doesn’t seem to be haram (forbidden) in a common situation (e.g. wearing usual sport short in soccer). But AFAIK there seems to be sin as an impermissible practice in wearing very short/tight Short which lead to sin …

E.g. as a relatively a related issue, it has asked regarding the ruling of wearing specific clothes of the sports such as wrestling/weight-lifting and so on, the answer of Ayatullah Khamenei as a famous Shi’a scholar/Marja’al-Taqlid is that:

> حضرت آیة الله خامنه ای(مدظله): اگر ترویج آن باعث گناه و بی بند و باری
>   باشد جایز نیست.
>
> Namely:
>
> It is not permissible if its promotion would be led in sin and
>   promiscuity.

**Consequently,** the following Fatwa of Ayatollah Khamenei can be deemed as a general formula to recognize similar issues. (So, I assume, although the clothes of wrestling/weight-lifting seem to be worse than soccer, you'd better try not to wear short/tight short in order to prevent sin (although what I perceived of your text, doesn't look haram)

---

**Source:**

- http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=207451

  http://farsi.khamenei.ir/news-content?id=27847

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him, His family and companions.

> Narrated Zur'ah bin Muslim bin Jardah Al-Aslami: about his grandfather
>   Jarhad, he said: "The Prophet (ﷺ) passed by Jarhad in the Masjid and
>   his thigh was exposed, so he said: 'Indeed the thigh is
>   'Awrah.'"(Tirmidhi)

Awrah refers to the parts of the body that have to be covered with fine clothing.

Awrah for men is from below the navel to below the knee from the front, back and sides. Sunnah is to wear loose clothing.

So if these parts of your body are covered then it is not considered as Haram (Sunni View).

> Narrated Bahz bin Hakim: from his father, from his grandfather, who
>   said: "I said: 'O Prophet of Allah! Regarding our 'Awrah, what of it
>   must we cover and what of it may we leave?' He said: 'Protect your
>   'Awrah except from your wife or what your right hand possesses.' He
>   said: "I said: 'O Messenger of Allah! What about when some people are
>   with others?' He said: 'If you are able to not let anyone see it then
>   do not let them see it.'" He said: "I said: 'O Prophet of Allah! What
>   about when one of us is alone?' He said: 'Allah is more deserving of
>   being shy from Him than the people.'"

Also see [this](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2014/05/26/covering-the-nakedness-for-a-man-answers/).

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.